# Spring Test @ActiveProfiles alternative?

Tags: java, spring, spring-test, spring-profiles

I want to set active profiles for tests with outside variables - for example, VM options. Have I any variations to do it?

Variant 1: set `@ActiveProfiles` with variable, like `@ActiveProfile("${testProfile:test}")` - not working or I don't know how.

Variant 2: with any context settings, something like `WebContextInitializer` (not working for tests).

Have any ideas?

Comment: and you dont want to use application.properties for different profiles?

Comment: how to do it? what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use ActiveProfilesResolver

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfilesResolver.html

See example below:

```
public class MyActiveProfilesResolver  implements ActiveProfilesResolver{
  @Override
  public String[] resolve(Class<?> testClass) {
      String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
      String profile = (os.toLowerCase().startsWith("windows")) ? "windows" : "other";
      return new String[]{profile};
  }
}


@ActiveProfiles(resolver = MyActiveProfilesResolver.class)
public class MyServiceTests {

}
```

Comment: No, I want to setup "test" in @ActiveProfile("test") from outside.

Comment: good way, but how to send VM options to resolver?

Comment: Why don't you simple use the jvm param `-Dspring.profiles.active`? You can also set this in your pom for the test phase if you use maven. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles. If you want to run the test(s) manually, you can configure your IDE to add the param.